# Automatically replace one variable name with another

Tags: javascript

I've been searching for ways to make my code more concise, so I want to find a way to automatically replace an identifier with an abbrevation of that identifier (whenever I type that identifier). It would be similar to the "autocorrect" feature that is found in some word processors.

Example:

```
var con = console.log;
//from this point on, whenever I type "console.log" as a variable name, I want the text to be automatically replaced with "con"
```

Comment: I'd need some way to avoid replacing matches of `con` inside string literals, like this: `"con"`. I'd most likely need to use a Javascript parser (to distinguish between identifiers and string literals).

Comment: Some IDEs have automatic code replacement features, don't they?

Comment: As a workaround, I could simply prevent a function from being called in a certain section of code, and then allow it to be called again after a certain point - it's a clumsy workaround, but it might work in a very limited number of scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
var con = function(str){console.log(str);};
con('hello world'); //=> hello world
```

It looks like you want to be able to use a kind of [intellisense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) or [autocomplete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete). Your editor should provide that. You can try [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit/downloads) or [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718325.aspx) (2012). In Komodo Edit the above code example leads to autocompletion (it shows `con` if you typed 'co').

Comment: I'm trying to automatically replace one identifier with another identifier (as described in the original post).

Comment: I hope the wording of my question is clearer now - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You may be interested in some obfuscator then, like googles closure compiler: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is automatically replace variable names with abbreviations as I type (sort of like an AutoCorrect feature). I have clarified the question's wording again - hopefully it is less vague now.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code long hand, and run it through an obfuscator, such as [one of the packages previously described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)

Comment: What I'm trying to do specifically is automatically replace variable names with abbreviations as I type - I don't think an obfuscator would do that. Also, an obfuscator would make code difficult to read, and I want it to remain human-readable.

Comment: To what end, @AndersonGreen?

Comment: I'm basically trying to find an "autocorrect" feature that encourages the use of abbreviations instead of full variable names - it's easier to learn abbreviations when they're being automatically suggested to you as you type.